# Why can't the type of a first-class function contain byrefs?

Tags: f#

For example, the following isn't allowed, and I'm not sure why:

```
> let f () = 
    let f2 (a : byref<int>) =
        ()
    let mutable a = 0
    f2 &a;;
```

My guess would be that the byref could be a mutable reference to a stack variable, which could go out of scope if f2 decides to store it somewhere. Or is it something else?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `> let f () = 
            let f2 (a : byref<int>) =
                ()
            let mutable a = 0
            f2 &a;;

            ()
            --------^^

     C:\Users\mfaiza\AppData\Local\Temp\stdin(21,9): error FS0425: The type of a first-class function cannot contain byrefs`

Comment: Well, that's just a language limitation. It has to do with the idea of a function as something that takes an input and produces an output, and a `byref` parameter is not exactly an "input", but rather both input+output. If you want the function to mutate a cell, just have it return the modified value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .NET type system does not allow byref types to be used as generic type arguments (e.g. you can't create a `List<byref<int>>`).  Since (first class) F# functions are actually instances of the `FSharpFunc<_,_>` type, this means that F# functions also can't use byrefs in their domain or range.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to stem from the fact that you are declaring `f2` as a nested function. If you extract it from beneath `f`, it compiles:

```
let f2 (a : int byref) = ()

let f () =
    let mutable a = 1
    f2 &a
```